# Generate Attachment Based on PDF Web Link

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

From my understanding, when you attach a file on a record, it will show up in the Notes & Attachment section of the record. This will create a contentDocumentId for the attachment along with the contentDocumentLink and the LinkEntityId for the object.

Instead of going through this attachment process, what if we have the following:

1. Have a custom object called **document__c**. This object contains fields such as fileURL, fileName, fileType. A record of document__c will be created for each attachment. This process will not create any contentDocumentId, contentDocumentLink because there is no file in salesforce, only document__c record that holds the metadata of where the file is (on a remote server.).

My question here is: **Is there a way for me to generate an attachment of the file, attach it onto a record using the fileURL that points to the file on the remote server?** The file is a PDF with the link https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/44678.pdf

Comment: Take a look at [Files Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_admin_files_connect.htm&language=en_US&type=5) and/or [Salesforce CMS](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cms_customcontenttypes.htm&type=5), they both support your use case.